# Loading string from DB with EntityFramework escapes it

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, escaping

I have:

nvarchar in DB :   `blbala\nblaba`

When I load it with EF and give away through the webservice, I become `blbala\\nblaba`
So my questions are why it happens and how can I change it? I want my string to be exactly as in the DB.

Thanks

Upd: My webservice gives then the answer in JSON format. The same double `\` (`0x5C`) I can observe in Chrome and in Fiddler (including HexView Window). So I think it's not the debugger who makes this.

Comment: In what format are you seeing it when it's sent through a webservice? Json?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing that as an artifact of the debugger you're using? The VS debugger, for example, shows strings with doubled backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Its the Visual Studio debugger that is fooling you. It escapes the charecters and thats what you see in your debug view. You can work around that by adding the variable to the `Watch` Window adding `,nq` (no quotes) like this:

```
"MyVariable,nq"
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, it works for the debugger, but as I wrote in the Update above the problem is seen not only in debugger, but also in WebService JSON formatted output

Comment: Could you add the json output?